# Redux store structuring for different loading actions

Tags: redux

I have a TodoList where it is possible to change, delete etc. single Todos. When a TodoItem gets altered a Http request is made. I would like to block the submit button and show the user that it is loading. But I am struggling with how to structure the store.

One idea I came up was to add a flag for each action like changing, deleting etc. to every TodoItem, but this solution seems a bit cumbersome:

```
store : {
  todos: {
    items: [
      {
        id: 5,
        text: "foo bar",
        action: {
          changing: true, // Is set after user submitted change until server response
          deleting: false // Is set after user clicked delete button until server response
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the best practice to store different loading-actions on the same item?

Answer (score 1):

You should store `string` as the value for your `action` like:

```
    store : {
      todos: {
        items: [
          {
           id: 5,
           text: "foo bar",
           action: "changing", // or "deleting"
         }
       ]
    }
```

On a side note - you should keep your state as normalised as possible.
You can read about it more on [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)